# Как сгенерировать новый UID NFC

Tags: java, kotlin

Как сгенерировать новый UID NFC  с возможностью записывать данные, например через NFC Tools

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://learn.gototags.com/nfc/chip/features/uid